# Custom queries with Entity Framework 5 and MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Make custom¹ queries in an application who uses C#.NET + MVC 4 + Entity Framework + MySQL.

### The problem

I want to perform a query and return the results to view, but I don't know how to do.

### What I have

The follow query that returns some `productName`, `minProductprice`, `maxProductPrice` *(and I want to display this on my view)*:

```
SELECT MIN(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `minProductPrice`,
       MAX(`map`.`Product_Price`) as `maxProductPrice`,
       `pr`.`Product_Name` as `productName`
FROM `bm_market_products` `map` join
     `bm_products` as `pr`
     on map`.`Product_Id` = `pr`.`Product_Id`
group by `map`.`Product_Id`
```

### Duplicate question?

I think not. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748988/custom-queries-in-mvc-4-entity-framework) and has a similar title, but it seems that the context is different.

### The question

So, how can I follow with my problem?

### Details

¹: *"custom"* means something out of default CRUD created by Entity Framework. The query that I have showed before was not done by default — and I want to perform it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the user input is sql?

Comment: ok, whay do you mean by `custom`

Comment: use linq 2 entities. Or if you don't want to rewrite the query, then save it as stored procedure. Or use just 'pure' ado.net (google for SqlCommand or SqlDataAdapter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Brian S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982949/brian-s), I could conclude that the more concise way is with **Stored Procedures**. I am beginner at all and I found the solution [right here, on "Using Store Routines" post at MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html).

By the way, thanks for the help.

### Update v1

["Querying MySQL using Entity Framework and MySQL Stored Procedures"](http://sunali.com/2012/10/10/querying-mysql-using-entity-framework-and-mysql-stored-procedures/) by [Coskun Sunali](http://sunali.com/author/admin/) is a post who teaches a good way to work with EF + Stored Procedures. For me as beginner, was a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Why not you can use SqlDataAdapter and DataSet as Entity framework is now aware about "dynamic queries" And then you can display them where you need.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [`ExecuteStoreQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) method of the `ObjectContext` (which the `DbContext` derives from to execute SQL directly).  I am not sure this is the best approach, but after much searching, it was the best approach I could find:

```
public class ResultObject
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal MinProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal MaxProductPrice { get; set; }
}

//Within your Control or somewhere common
public IList<TResult> ExecuteSql<TResult>(string sql)
{
    var results = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<TResult>(sql);
    return results;
}

//Then, when you need the results, call the ExecuteSql method:
var productInfo = ExecuteSql<ResultObject>(mySql);
```

All the standard warnings apply about inline-sql, including scrubbing user-input data, and how it's a bad idea (you should probably consider a Stored Procedure).  This will work for a Stored Procedure as well, as you can pass a Parameters collection in to the `ExecuteStoreQuery` method if desired.

Comment: Hello, Brian. Thank you about your entry. You quoted "Stored Procedure", right? Can you give me a more details about it? And about the code you posted — can you exemplify the files where they go? Thank you again!

Comment: Hi @chiefGui.  Information about Stored Procedures could fill a book, but if you'd like to learn more, you could start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx).  There are lots of resources for learning more on the internet.  As far as where the code I provided goes, it depends on how you've organized your code.  The tags indicate ASP.NET MVC4, which means you'll have a controller.  If the controller owns the EF DbContext, then you can put all this code in your Controller.  The ExecuteSql method just needs to be where it can access the DbContext.

Comment: Thanks about the Stored Procedures explanation — I will read about this. About the code organization: `ResultObejct` will be a class inside of my product's controller? And I'm not finding `ExecuteSql<TResult>` nor `IObjectContextAdapter` — maybe a namespace? Thank you again.

Comment: If the only place you're using the ResultObject is in this 1 controller, then yes, it can be a nested class inside this controller.  If you need it beyond just this controller, you can declare it outside the controller where it can be used elsewhere.  I have linked the `ExecuteStoreQuery` name above to the MSDN page for the method, so clicking on it will give you more details.  The namespace is System.Data.Objects and it is in the System.Data.Entity assembly.

Comment: Actually I will follow your advice: stored procedures. I am searching about it and seems it is the best way. Anyway, thank you about everything.

Comment: Sounds good, Stored Procedures are a much better approach than in-line SQL.  You'll need the same code to execute the SP from your code, so once you've got it all figured out and working, if this solves your problem, please mark it as the answer to close the loop.  Good luck!